# Don't show the number of suggested edits while under a review ban

Tags: feature-request, suggested-edits, review-suspension

My fat-fingered self failed an audit, which gave me a two-day review ban. However, I'm still seeing the number of suggested edits in the navbar. Shouldn't this be removed?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This number is not a per user value. It's the total number of reviews **of all kinds** not just suggested edits available to all users with your privileges. While you may be banned from reviewing suggested edits you should be able to review close votes (for example).

As such it's not 100% accurate already (there are other questions on here about that) as it includes reviews that you've skipped or are otherwise currently unavailable but one that you *could* review.

One reason it's like this is that it would be too expensive to calculate on an individual basis and would also be still wrong a lot of the time as other people reviewed posts and removed them from the queues.

Comment: I'm not asking for increased accuracy, just that it's hidden if you're under a review ban. (Just as if I didn't have the privilege to review.)

Comment: @Mooseman - I wasn't clear, that number includes **all** review queues not just suggested edits.

Comment: Review cost votes? Does that mean we have to decide whether or not to charge a fee to a user for voting?

Comment: @ChrisF It's only all reviews for 10k+ users. Still just edits until then.

Comment: @BillyMailman - ah. That explains the confusion.